# How can I override default .eslint rules at runtime in a create-react-app project

Tags: create-react-app

I've just tried updating to create-react-app 4, and have a ton of typescript eslint warnings, particularly
Missing return type on function  @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types

Is there any way to override these in a .eslintrc.json file for runtime?
I've currently got overrides that work there for my project when I explicitly execute

`npm run lint`

But when I use `npm run start` I get a ton of lint warnings that I can't seem to control.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there is a way to override the .eslint rules.

1. Create a .env file in your root, if you don't have one.
2. Add the following to it as a new line: `EXTEND_ESLINT=true`
3. Extend the lint rules in your favorite way.  I use `.eslintrc.json` but other mechanisms exist

Now with that in place, have a look at the included rules from react, which live in
`node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\index.js` and copy the rules you like into your rules section.

You may also want to pay careful attention to the overrides section, examples of which you can see in the above file, and if you have js in your project, you may want to remove the default parser,

`parser: 'babel-eslint'`
and then only override for typescript files.